# Is this structure, Adj. as it seems, correct?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I wish to express

> Although it may sound good, its assumption is questionable and risky.

I remember vaguely that I have read it as such from somewhere I cannot remember:

> Good as it may sound, its assumption is questionable and risky.

Is it correct? Or it should be:

> Good as it may sound, **but** its assumption is questionable and
>   risky.

Comment: You don't want the *but*.  You could also add an *As* at the beginning:  *As good as it may sound, its assumption is questionable and risky.*

Comment: @Jim I *could also* add? So the first *as* is optional?

Comment: I'd call dropping the first 'As' *informal speech*. I'd never do that in a formal paper.

Comment: @Jim Ok thanks! I am writing a formal paper. So I will keep the *as*. :)

Comment: No _but_. This is archaic syntax and you shouldn't fool with it unless you understand all the details. Which are incredibly boring.

Comment: @JohnLawler  So you think better use the "although..., ..." or "While..., ...." instead?

Comment: Yes. Until you're checked out on instrument flight, better not solo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sentence can be correct but still sound awkward. For me, the first sentence falls into that camp. The second one sounds better, and the third is definitely ungrammatical.